# Class AB Amplifier - Q point

Tags: amplifier, class-ab

In a class AB amplifier, why is the Q point much closer to the cutoff voltage as compared to a Class A amplifier which is at the center. Wouldn't this clip the AC signal if its too close to Vce.

Also, notice -Vcc, would the transistor (TR2) still operate if -Vcc is grounded?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class A biasing usually refers to a single transistor. Yes, Class A requires \$I_Q\$ to be about half-way. Class AB usually refers to two-transistor (push-pull), where one transistor takes care of upper half, while the other transistor takes care of lower half. Class B would set \$I_Q\$ at zero...Class AB offsets \$I_Q\$ with extra \$V_{BIAS}\$.

Your source diagram shows \$I_Q\$ for only **one transistor** (perhaps the NPN). A more complete load-line diagram might include biasing for both NPN & PNP transistor overlaid, as below. Note that with no **Input signal** the NPN+PNP transistors both are biased with \$I_Q\$ current flowing from **+VCC** through NPN collector-to-emitter, through PNP emitter-to-collector, to **-VCC**. This current establishes a linear **load line** through the zero signal point:
[image: NPN+PNP class AB bias]

The NPN is supplying current to **Output** during the signal swings that are above the average. The PNP supplies current to **Output** during the signal swings that are below the average.

For the example circuit, a single polarity DC supply would work. But be aware that this is a somewhat conceptual, simple schematic, and wouldn't likely be seen in the real world.